# CAML Query on "Person" field type

Tags: list, caml-query

I would like to query list and get items that were created by specific user, in my list I have the fild "User" of type Person

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
<Where>
 <Eq>
  <FieldRef Name='User' />
   <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>
 </Eq>
</Where>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work"? Did you get an error? Were no results returned? What is the ID of the user you are searching for on the site? Where is this code running?

Comment: This is working like a charm, my only doubt when i used in u2u caml query tool no results cameup any clues?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks Alex, that article helped!

What I was missing is "LookupId='TRUE'" in the  tag should has , the following is the corrected query:

```
<Where>
 <Eq>
  <FieldRef Name='User' LookupId='TRUE' />
   <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>
 </Eq>
</Where>
```

Comment: I'm glad to help. :)

Answer (score 9):

http://www.stum.de/2008/02/06/querying-the-person-or-group-field-using-spquery/