# Querying a simple list with a 'User' column, using CAML

Tags: filter, query, caml

I'm having some trouble getting a CAML Query working against a very simple list.

My custom list has the fields:

- Person : User
- Date : Date
- Amount : Lookup

My query looks like this:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Person' LookupId='TRUE' />
      <Value Type='Integer'>{0}</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

and {0} contains an integer.

**Problem**

My list contains 8 elements, divided between two seperate users. My query is supposed to get me 4 elements back, but is always returning 8.

I have been researching this for quite some time now (using both U2U Query Builder, and trying to handwrite it) but have been unable to get it to filter.

Please advise!

**Solution**

The solution was to remove the `<Query></Query>` from the CAML Query-string. The below accepted answer doesn't adress this, though it is also correct.

Comment: Did you have a look at this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29079/caml-query-on-person-field-type ? And: Does the filtering work in the U2U Query Builder?

Comment: Remove <Query></Query>, see if it helps

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to use this caml:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Author" LookupId="True" />
    <Value Type="User">123</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

this also might work, but first is preferable:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Author" LookupId="True" />
    <Value Type="Lookup">123</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

and also, if you want to pass current logged user into caml query, you can use this one:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Author" />
    <Value Type="Integer">
      <UserID />
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

Comment: Nice tip there on the last one, didn't know that.

Comment: Here is what mine looks like.  <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Author" LookupId="True" /><Value Type="User"><UserID /></Value></Eq></Where>

Comment: how to pass a  spuser variable ? like i am saving the spuser                            string strnp11user =@"mydomain\NPD11";

                        SPUser objuser1 = spWeb.EnsureUser(strnp11user);   how to pass this  objuser1 inside the caml query? i

Comment: Here's another tip: the third example has whitespace in the <Value> element. But if you do that in example 1 or 2, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the **system account** (probably in your development environment (Virtual Machine)), the  **does not work as expected**.

The user **Purna** said the same thing [in this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/de0ffdd4-c3b0-40c3-882d-076c92e287a7/how-to-query-the-task-items-assigned-to-current-user?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/de0ffdd4-c3b0-40c3-882d-076c92e287a7/how-to-query-the-task-items-assigned-to-current-user?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy).