# Query by user field returns wrong number of items

Tags: caml, query

I'm trying to query a list in an eventreceiver through properties.List.GetItems (in the itemadding event). The field I'm filtering on is a 'Person or Group' field. But the query always returns all items instead of just the ones having the user I provided.

I'm using following code:

I've already checked following post:
[link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35975/querying-a-simple-list-with-a-user-column-using-caml) but this didn't resolve my problem.

the query I use is:

```
<Where>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='Gebruiker' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Integer'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>
```

I Also tried:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Gebruiker' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Lookup'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>
```

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

I found it in the meanwhile :)

When I passed the query as a string to the GetItems function it wasn't working correctly.
However when I create a SPQuery-object, pass the query (the string) to the Query property of that object and then pass that object to the GetItems function it works correctly :) .