# caml query for text field(Title field) contains username in SharePoint hosted app

Tags: list, list-view, caml-query, sharepoint-hosted-app, schema

In my hosted app I have one text field which contains username. I want to apply filter on a view which on filtering gives me data related to current user.

```
<Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="Name" Required="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" FromBaseType="TRUE" ColName="nvarchar1" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Version="1" RowOrdinal="0" />
```

I can only have above text field to apply filter. How to apply caml query for this situations

Comment: How come you are not using a user-column?

Answer (score 3):

A CAML query for that would look something like this

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                <Value Type='Text'>username</Value>
            </Contains>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

But I do wonder why you are not using a field of user type, to be able to do a better filtering (and a better GUI for the end users)

Comment: will the username replaced with current logged in username

Comment: You would need to manually place the current users login name there in your scenario. 

If you instead use a user column you could put in `<UserID />` as outlined here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35975/querying-a-simple-list-with-a-user-column-using-caml/35979

Comment: is there a possible solution without using user column

Comment: Not without you creating the CAML-query yourself (eg. pass in the username dynamically)

Comment: do you have any reference for this condition

Comment: What condition are you referring to?

Comment: pass in the username dynamically for text field

Comment: That is completely dependent on your application and where you are executing the CAML-query from..